# why data-attribute shows undefined while getting data value from HTML element using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yovivek/k08w167j/1/)

I am trying to get the data attributes value of an HTML element it shows undefined `object[]` nothing goes work for me. Check my fiddle.

```
$(document).on("click", ".modal-open", function() {
    var $_target = $($(this).data("targetlocation"));
    var $_url = $($(this).data("targeturl"));
    console.log($_target);
    console.log($_url);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using identifier with multiple words, You need to use `camelCase` notation

```
var $_target = $(this).data("targetLocation"); //Notice L 
var $_url = $(this).data("targetUrl");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3r91go4b/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
var $_target = $(this).attr("data-target-location");
var $_url = $(this).attr("data-target-url");
```

or

```
var $_target = $(this).data("target-location");
var $_url = $(this).data("target-url");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r6rkq6wk/)**

Answer (score 1):

if you are going with this html Element

```
 <button type="button" class="modal-open" data-target-url="ajax.html" data-target-location=".overlay"> Modal open </button>
```

after triggering a click event on button "this" will return same html Element,
therefore to fetch current data attribute value of this type.

You should use  Camel Casing notation.

```
var $_target = $(this).data("targetLocation");
var $_url = $(this).data("targetUrl");
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k08w167j/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".modal-open").on("click", function() {

        var $_target = $(this).attr("data-target-location");
        var $_url = $(this).attr("data-target-url");
        alert($_target);
        alert($_url);
     });
```

Use this for Getting Attributes

Demo for this shows there [**`Demo There`**](http://jsfiddle.net/k08w167j/4/)